# Google Fit show select an account then close and return access denied

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-fit

I am developing an application in Flutter, which retrieves podometric data through Apple Health and Google Fit.
Apple Health is correctly configured.
Google Fit does not work.
The application asks for access to the data, it opens the pop up select an account then nothing happens, and the value returned corresponding to the access is false.

I am using the :   health: ^3.0.3

I am requesting access like this:

```
DateTime endDate = DateTime.now();
DateTime startDate =
    widget.user.lastTimeRecoverHealthData.add(Duration(seconds: 1));
HealthFactory health = HealthFactory();
List<HealthDataType> types = [
  HealthDataType.STEPS,
  HealthDataType.DISTANCE_WALKING_RUNNING,
];
List<HealthDataPoint> healthData;

health.requestAuthorization(types).then((value) {
  print("health.requestAuthorization: THEN");
  print("then return ${value}");
  if (value) {
      [...]
  }
})
```

I can't find where I miss a step in the Google fit and Android process.
Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure the package name you registered to your project on Google Cloud Platform is matched with the package name from the app you are develop.

Check the OAuth 2.0 Client IDs from Credentials on your Google Cloud Console.
I ran into same problem you described and my mistake was the name from the Credentials is was not match with my app's package name.

Comment: Did you just change the package name?
I checked the package name and it is good, but the SHA-1 fingerprint was not the right one. I changed the SHA-1 fingerprint then save.
But the problem is still present: the Oauth pop up appears, asks to select the account. When I select the account the pop up closes and the Authorization token returns 'FLUTTER_HEALTH(26443): Access Denied!'.

And the page that describes that I want to retrieve the number of steps, and kilometers traveled is never shown.

Comment: I changed the package name from GG Console Dev matched with my app package name. And you should make sure the fingerprint is generated with correct debug keystore(https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849#installedapplications&android)
And in OAuth Consent Screen on GG Console Dev, you add the user email which you use to test your app( the account must login into g Google Play Store app on the device you going to test your app).

Comment: Yes I'm getting familiar with the Google Fit api I delivered four apps that required Google Fit since this problem.
Can I help you?

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY GOT THIS ISSUE SOLVED!!

So the problem doesn't lie in the version I am using 3.4.0 but still got the problem solved

> **Authorization not granted. And  stuck in loading screen**

[Stuck in authorization request screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LrWc.png)

When you create your OAuth 2.0 consent screen try to add at least 2 email addresses to the **TEST USER** section and make sure to login from that emails.

[[Add 2 email addresses in Test User](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent)][2](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent)

After that make sure to verify your application from Google, it will work until you test your app once you release the application, it will not work

[Verify Your Application from Google](https://developers.google.com/fit/verification)

Final Result
[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjCT5.jpg)